# How to Use Datatables in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, datatables

I had use Data tables in core PHP and trying to use it in code igniter Framework. I am new to framework , how can i will implement it to code igniter?

Comment: Here is a good tutorial: http://www.ahmed-samy.com/php-codeigniter-full-featrued-jquery-datatables-part-1/

Answer (score 7):

Is googling that difficult?

There's a special DataTables library made for Codeigniter.

https://github.com/IgnitedDatatables/Ignited-Datatables/

> To install the library, copy the libraries/datatables.php file into
>   your application/libraries folder

A usage guide can be found [HERE](https://github.com/IgnitedDatatables/Ignited-Datatables/wiki/Function-Reference)

Comment: I don't get why people watch their profile, but not look at the questions they asked..